# What is the right verb for "knowledge" as in when we know something? Do we form knowledge, acquire knowledge, make knowledge, ...?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the verb we use that describes **what we do when we get some new knowledge?**

It seems to me that we "acquire/obtain/gain knowledge" but then such verbs have a strong sense of activeness while sometimes we just passively know things.

Comment: What context do you need it for? Because we do acquire knowledge, but we also have knowledge and can use it once we've acquired it and we can have it of many topics etc.....

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen What we do with knowledge just the moment we know something? Do we make knowledge?

Comment: I'll say this half-jokingly, but...grok? This means more "to have total understanding," and can describe acquisition, or an indefinite/perpetual state of knowing and understanding. Anyway, if you're truly looking for a one word solution...Only problem is that it isn't a "real" word. Though I've gotten away with using it in some academic papers :)

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the body in bold do not seem to be in tandem.

Comment: "We **know**" don't we?

Comment: @HimabinduBoddupalli What about now?

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. Anyways, I have answered the question in the body.

Answer (score 3):

In the collocations 'acquire knowledge' and 'gain knowledge', the connotation of 'making an effort to' is not all that strong: bleaching has taken place
. 'Wrest' would be used to show a real battle, with the knowledge hard-won; 'amass' might be used to show a steady compilation.

But **acquire knowledge by osmosis** is an expression aimed at showing the near-accidental acquisition of knowledge as one lives one's normal life.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/osmosis) has:

> *osmosis* mass noun ...
>
> 2 The process of gradual or unconscious assimilation of ideas,
>   knowledge, etc.
>
> *‘by some strange political osmosis, private reputations became public’*
>
> *‘During my time as a model, I learned almost through osmosis because I dealt with people on an ongoing basis,’ she said.*

An example from [Knowledge and Democracy: A 21st Century Perspective
edited by Nico Stehr](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IyuK-6hWO2AC&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22knowledge+by+osmosis%22&source=bl&ots=7ymhgQd45x&sig=GVxBS3uxQUnhJirbwuffqF6Rs1c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWwe3U4_bUAhXhC8AKHXgIDPUQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=%22knowledge%20by%20osmosis%22&f=false):

> *... It would certainly be quicker than picking up the relevant knowledge by osmosis over many years ...*

(note the informal 'pick[ing] up' used here).

And one from [NEJM Journal Watch HIV Expertise: A Roundtable](http://www.jwatch.org/ac200109010000008/2001/09/01/hiv-expertise-roundtable):

> ' *... when you go into a clinic and acquire knowledge by osmosis, ..*.'

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for **assimilate**? This answers your question written in bold.

Assimilate

> take in and understand fully (information or ideas)

This is what you do when you get some new knowledge. You assimilate it before you finally store it in your memory.

e.g. I was speechless, still trying to assimilate the enormity of what he'd told me.

Example source : [Here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/assimilate)

Comment: Those downvoting the answer are requested to justify their action.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

**Absorb**

> [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/absorb): 5.  To learn; acquire: "Matisse *absorbed* the lesson and added to it a new language of color"

This is often used in context of early human development, particularly in the [Montessori philosophy](http://ageofmontessori.org/the-ten-secrets-of-montessori-education-3-the-absorbent-mind/):

> One of Maria Montessori’s most important and fundamental discoveries was what she called “the absorbent mind.” During the first six years of life, children have a very different way of learning than adults. At this age, children have sponge-like brains; they are able to soak up vast amounts of information from their environment. And they do so effortlessly, continuously, and indiscriminately.